# In Matthew 6:10 should it be translated "on the earth" or "in the earth?

Tags: matthew, translation-philosophy, lords-prayer

Matthew 6:10  in the Authorized King James version. Say IN Earth and most other versions says ON Earth. To me there is a difference of In and On. Also the Earth and World are not the same. God created the Earth, Man created the World. And there are scripture with IN this world. What is the true version IN or ON Earth?

Comment: That's not a matter of translation.  It's a matter of preposition usage in Middle English and Modern English.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the Matt 6:10 reads: "os en ourano kai epi ges", which I would literally render: "as in heaven, also on earth/land".

The simple answer to the question: the Greek preposition "epi" simply means "upon", or "on".  The preposition preceding heaven is "en" which is generally translated "in".  Interestingly, the Greek word "ge", when preceeded by a preposition, it is most often "epi" = "upon" or "on" or "eis" = "into" or in.  "Into the land" (eg Matt 2:20) usually refers to some country, while "upon the land/earth" usually refers to activity that is conducted or something that happens (eg, Matt 10:29).

Lastly, recall, that the ancients had no concept that we inhabit a planet that orbits the sun - such is very modern.  The word for earth is the Greek "ge" which is better translated "land", or "earth" meaning arable land or soil and is the consistent meaning throughout Scripture.  This is the same word that LXX uses in Gen 1:1, "... God created the heavens and the earth (Gr: "ge"; see also Gen 1:10 where this definition is explicit.).

The word for "world" is generally a translation of the Greek, "kosmos", meaning orderly or well arranged (see ANLEX).  By extension it is used to refer to what we now describe as the universe.

Comment: My understanding of κοσμος, _cosmos_, is that it is the 'habitable world' or 'civilised world' as opposed to γε, _ge_, the entirety of the created earth. The 'heavens' is that which is beyond and above the earth. In my own understanding.

Comment: @Nigel J - I agree with you about kosmos.  However, some versions translate it "universe" in 1 Cor 4:9 and Phil 4:9.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught in seminary:  "IN Earth" - Adam, first man, his name is derived from "earth or dirt", not kosmos like, "...For God so loved the WORLD - Kosmos.." but,  "...thy will be done IN earth (or man/Adam) as it is IN heaven (or God)..."  Conclusion: "...may your will be done in ME, as in You/God..."

Your thoughts please.

Answer (score 0):

In earth. Our faith should dictate His Will is going to be done ON Earth no matter what so we don't need to ask Him that. Instead, man is created from earth and we should pray His Will, which is to glorify Him, be done in us

Comment: Hi Ron, welcome to the site. This answer would benefit from a little more elaboration. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Comment: Further is Heaven is a place of agape and we ask for His help to keep this in us (earth).